# "Comic store" in French

Tags: demande-de-mot

What is the general term for a comic store in French? I know that most book stores have a section dedicated to comics, but I'd like to find specialised comic stores. What are they called?

Comment: Do you know about the Musée de la bande dessinée in Angoulême, France? They call theirs: librairie de la bande dessinée et de l'image. https://librairie.citebd.org/la-librairie/ssh-1288

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Un magasin qui vend des livres est une *librairie*. Un magasin qui ne vend que certains types de livres est une *librairie spécialisée*. Un magasin qui ne vend que des bandes dessinées est une ***librairie spécialisée en bandes dessinées***.

On peut aussi dire *librairie spécialisée en bande dessinée*. « Bandes dessinées » est au pluriel si l'on fait référence aux objets vendus (comme dans *librairie spécialisée en livres d'art*, *librairie spécialisée en livres anciens*) ou au singulier si l'on fait référence au domaine (comme dans *librairie spécialisée en histoire* ou *librairie spécialisée jeunesse*). Il existe de nombreuses variations plus ou moins abrégées : « librairie spécialisée dans la bande dessinée », « librairie de bandes dessinées », etc.

*Bande dessinée* est très souvent abrégé *BD*. On trouve quelquefois l'orthographe *bédé*. On parle souvent de *mangas* pour les BD de style japonais, et quelquefois de *comics* pour les BD de style américain. En France, il y a quelques librairies spécialisées en mangas (où l'on trouve souvent d'autres livres et autres objets culturels japonais), mais pas tellement en *comics*. Les librairies de BD ont en général des rayons *comics* et *mangas*.

Pour faire une recherche sur Internet, « librairie BD » devrait trouver toutes les librairies spécialisées et les librairies généralistes qui mettent en avant leur rayon BD.

Au passage, une *bédéthèque* est une bibliothèque spécialisée en bandes dessinées. La plupart des bédéthèques font partie d'une bibliothèque généraliste.